# JavaScript array cloning

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have this way to make an array

```
var playerList = [];

exports.player = function(socket, name)
{
    this.id = socket.id;
    this.name = name;
    this.x = 20;
    this.y = 40;

    return this
}

exports.addPlayer = function(data)
{
    playerList.push(data)
}
```

And I'm adding items to `playerList` array like this

```
var client = new player(socket, data);
exports.addPlayer(client);
```

But I also got a function that makes the following

```
exports.getSafeList = function(id)
{
    var player_array = playerList.slice();

    for(var i = 0; i < player_array.length; i++)
    {
        if(player_array[i].id != id)
        {
            player_array[i].id = 'unknown';
        }
    }

    return player_array;
}
```

And now I do the following

```
exports.getPlayerList = function()
{
    return playerList;
}

console.log(players.getPlayerList())
console.log(players.getSafeList(id))
```

So far the code is working fine but when I log the 2 functions it seems that `getPlayerList` variable merges with `player_list` one, this is the output

When theres just ONE player on the array

```
[ { id: 'tjvh8XdMtX-o6QYDAAAB', name: 'Raggaer', x: 20, y: 40 } ]

[ { id: 'tjvh8XdMtX-o6QYDAAAB', name: 'Raggaer', x: 20, y: 40 } ]
```

But when there are more:

```
[ { id: 'unknown', name: 'Raggaer', x: 20, y: 40 },
  { id: '2-K5At07wLV4BDiAAAAC', name: 'Alvaro', x: 20, y: 40 } ]

[ { id: 'unknown', name: 'Alvaro', x: 20, y: 40 },
  { id: '2-K5At07wLV4BDiAAAAC', name: 'Alvaro', x: 20, y: 40 } ]
```

As you can see on both arrays `id` appears as "unknown" when it shouldn't, since I'm not modyfing the `playerList` array...

Comment: `playerList.slice()` only creates a **shallow** copy. Both arrays will refer to the same objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will create a separate copy of the original array, its items will still be references to the same object instances. So modifying an item in one array ends up modifying the corresponding item in the cloned array.

If your items are simple data objects (no functions), this workaround might do the trick for you:

```
// instead of "var player_array = playerList.slice();"
var player_array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(playerList));
```