# Making new array with array.length

Tags: javascript

How can I sort `array.length` numerically? In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo041.png) my numbers generator should be ordered in descending order.

I tried creating a new array with the push function. My code is as follows:

```
var newArray = [];
newArray.push(myArray.length);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I'm a beginner in javascript and I haven't been able to find another solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="hack.js" defer></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div id="demo" style="width: 500px;border: 1px solid black;"></div>
  <script>
    var myNumbers = '';
for (var i = 10; i <= 40; i++) {
 var myArray = [];
 for (var j = 2; j < i; j++) {
  if (i % j == 0) {
   myArray.push(j); 
  }
 }
 myNumbers += "<p>" + i + " number of generators = " + myArray.length + '</p>';

}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myNumbers;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can make a multi-dimensional array with each index being `[number, generator]` and then just use `array.sort(function(a,b) { return a[1] - b[1] })` then print out your result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464864/javascript-array-cloning)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myNumbers = [];
for (var i = 10; i <= 40; i++) {
    var myArray = [];
    for (var j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            myArray.push(j);    
        }
    }
    var value = { int: i, length: myArray.length, html:"<p>" + i + " number of generators = " + myArray.length + '</p>' }
    myNumbers.push(value);

}
myNumbers.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
});

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myNumbers.map(function(d) { return d['html']; }).join('')
```

Comment: this is not the thing i want ... in the right side of the pic , i write the way i want

Comment: ahh. DIdn't see the pic. You can upload those into the question instead of an external link.

Answer (score 0):

first you can store mappings of numbers and their generator count in an array of objects. Then you can sort this array using a comparator function. The iterate over this array add elements based on this sorted array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="hack.js" defer></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div id="demo" style="width: 500px;border: 1px solid black;"></div>
  <script>
    var myNumbers = '', myArray = [];
for (var i = 10; i <= 40; i++) {
    var count = 0;
 for (var j = 2; j < i; j++) {
  if (i % j == 0) {
   count++;
  }
 }
    myArray.push({number: i, generators: count});
}
myArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.generators - a.generators;
});
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    myNumbers += "<p>" + myArray[i].number + " number of generators = " + myArray[i].generators + '</p>';

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myNumbers;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```